# Can I prevent Redis from expiring any keys?

Tags: redis

I'm importing an old Redis backup in order to browse its databases.
However upon launching Redis with the imported dump.rdb a lot of data is missing.
My guess is because Redis immediately expires all the old keys.

Is there a configuration setting to prevent Redis from expiring anything?

Answer (score 2):

Redis doesn't do that, but you can try setting the server's clock to some time in the distant past before loading the RDB.